# What does "direct" mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, definition, word-meaning

It's from "The Running Man" movie (1987)

In the begining there are opening credits which contain the back story of the movie.

> By 2017 the world economy has collapsed. Food, natural resources and 
>   oil are in short supply. A police state, divided into paramilitary 
>   zones, rules with an iron hand. Television is controlled by the state 
>   and a sadistic game show called "The Running Man" has become the most 
>   popular program in history. All art, music and communications are 
>   censored. No dissent is tolerated and yet a small resistance movement 
>   has managed to survive underground. When high-tech gladiators are not 
>   enough to suppress the people's yearning for freedom......more **direct** 
>   methods become necessary

.What exactly does "direct" mean in this context?

Comment: ***immediate***, ***focused***; in context of *more*: ***stronger***; in context of the dystopia: ***excessive***, ***oppressive***. Basically points 2 and 3 of the adjective in [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/direct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct, in this context, means straightforward. Direct methods of restricting freedom are methods that immediately cause a loss of freedom.

Providing people with the distraction of a violent TV show is an indirect way to suppress people's freedom. The relationship between the cause (the TV show) and the effect (people loose freedom) is not simple or straightforward: People watch the show -> they are not concerned with politics -> they don't protest or rebel -> the government can take their freedom.

But, this is not enough. A direct way of restricting freedom is to capture or kill protestors.